# How to stop a google map from continuously re-Centering at my location

Tags: java, android, maps

My problem is related to Google Maps in android. when moving the camera at any point, it returns to my original location instantly, How can I stop that? , You can find my code below 
The map starts normally and then for some reason it relocates it self to my original location when i try to navigate the map.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationmanager ;
    LocationListener locationlistener;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length> 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);

               Location lastKnownLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                centerMpOnLocation(lastKnownLocation, "your Location ");


            }
        }
    }

    public void centerMpOnLocation (Location location, String title){
            if (location != null){
            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            mMap.clear();
            if (title != "your Location") {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(title));
            }
               mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wait till we get your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

        Intent intent= getIntent();

        if (intent.getIntExtra("placeNumber", 0) == 0){

            locationmanager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationlistener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    centerMpOnLocation(location, "your Location");



                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            };

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
                locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
            }else {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

                }else{
                    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);

                    Location lastKnownLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    centerMpOnLocation(lastKnownLocation, "your Location");
                }

            }
        }else {

            Location placeLocation = new Location(locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            placeLocation.setLatitude(MainActivity.locations.get(intent.getIntExtra("placeNumber", 0)).latitude);
            placeLocation.setLongitude(MainActivity.locations.get(intent.getIntExtra("placeNumber", 0)).longitude);

            centerMpOnLocation(placeLocation, MainActivity.memorablePlaces.get(intent.getIntExtra("placeNumber", 0)));

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
       String address = "" ;
        try {
            List <Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);

            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0){
                if (addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null){
                    if (addresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() != null){
                        address += addresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() + " ";
                    }
                    address += addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                }
            }else if( address == "") { // عشان لو ماعرفتش اطلع عنوان هاحتاج اطلع تاريخ ووقت حاجه بديله يعنى

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd");

                address = sdf.format(new Date());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address));

        MainActivity.memorablePlaces.add(address);
        MainActivity.locations.add(latLng);
        MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}`
```

Anyone can fix this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are centering to your location, each time there is a location update.

```
locationlistener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    centerMpOnLocation(location, "your Location");



                }
    ...
    }
```

Remove **centerMpOnLocation(location, "your Location");** or change your logic.